# Error: Failure while executing: git stash pop --quiet

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I've gotten this error after running "brew update"

Homebrew seems to be having lots of errors with some Ruby files. Any hints on how to proceed from here would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`homebrew` is just a git repo. You can `cd $(brew --prefix)` and ensure that there's no local changes that are messing up with your update.

When you do `brew update` you should be getting a larger output than just the failure. If you post that we may be able to help you better.

To do a quick fix if you don't care about any changes made in your homebrew installation, simply cd into the homebrew repo using the command above and run `git reset --hard origin/master`. You should then be able to do the update.

Comment: wow i actually did not know this! my error message was much too long to post. i only had errors on .rb files... do you think it would still be beneficial to post?

Comment: Those errors are usually just changes that have been done to the git repo. These changes cause git to not be able to pop any stashed changes. It pretty much tells you that you have un saved changes in your repo. You could post the first few lines or follow my answer and just reset the repo. I'm assuming any changes lost won't be missed in any case.

Comment: wow you were right!! I was scared at first to do the git reset command but I went through with it and it worked perfectly. thanks so much